# Listening to electromagnetic fields

Tags: amplifier, audio, electromagnetism, music

In Nicolas Collins' book *Handmade Electronic Music* there is section on picking up electromagnetic fields and listen to them simply by connecting the wires to a RadioShack Mini Audio Amplifier. It says:

> You can solder a plug onto the wires coming out of any transformer [...], relay coil, solenoid, or electric motor, connect it to your amp and listen.

How can I make sure that I don't damage any of my equipment when I experiment with this using different types of transformers? For example if I connect a transformer from a DC power supply (or a powerful electric motor) to an audio amplifier to pick up magnetic fields, is there a risk to damage any equipment if the signal is too strong? What I can do to prevent the risks if there are any?

Comment: If you are talking about EM radiation in the audible range, you can do this with a single transistor. I did when I was a kid.

Comment: If you don't want to experiment with transistors (recommended though), pickup an [inductive amplifier](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=inductive+amplifier&t=opera&ia=web).  Interesting what many devices emit.  Just keep in mind that much of what it picks up will not be within the audible range today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really worth it unless it's portable.   You want to carry it all around your house, or walk around your neighborhood.

Wave the pickup-coil around a desktop PC or oldschool laptop.  Walk under electric bus overhead rails, and hear the bus that's several miles down the road.   Or, approach any modern car, and you'll hear many different switching supplies, serial comms to sensors, dimming dome-lights, etc.  (I think the car manufacturers don't bother shielding stuff, since it won't be interfering with oldschool television sets or household appliances located inside the car, etc.)

A pair of diodes hooked in parallel across it will limit the output to 0.6V.

It's basically a microphone, but for magnetic fields.   Even a dynamic microphone can destroy your front-end if you use it with gun-shots and firecrackers.   So, just stay away from EMP.   While listening, bring it near various AC b-fields, and if you hear something extremely loud, just keep it away from that source!

Note that transformers and electric motors don't work very well as inductive pickups (if you mean power transformers, with closed-loop lamination-paths.  Peel all the iron laminations off the power transformer, and just use the bare coil.)    But RF transformers will work (air core, or ferrite rod.)  Or most any coil-based relay, or a bare coil from an unshielded solenoid.   You just want a cylinder-coil with fifty or a thousand turns.

Or, buy the device intended for this application: the Radio Shack telephone "pickup coil" w/suction-cup, and 1/8in audio plug that fits many audio input jacks.   RS stopped selling them, so get them from ebay...

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=%22pickup+coil%22+telephone

Slowly wave a magnet near that sort of coil, and you hear roaring white-noise.  That's "quantum noise," Barkhausen effect, caused by spin-flipping of individual magnetic domains in the iron core.   Very thin iron foil makes very loud Barkhausen sound.

My own genius idea:  use a stereo headphone-amp, with two pickup coils glued together and oriented at 90deg.   (Doesn't give a stereo image of course.  It still sounds like "inside your head.")

Next, put a small photocell or photodiode on a small telescope, and listen to various light sources.   If you point it at a motorscycle headlight, even if miles away, it plays all sorts of "banging music" chords, from the vibrating tungsten filament.